# Which feature vector does opencv's K-Nearest-Neighbor algorithm use to predict in recognition.

Tags: opencv, ocr, feature-extraction, knn

I am trying to develop a basic OCR for bangla character using openCV. I have used opencv's built-in CvKNearest object. everything works alright except the accuracy of recognition. I haven't used any pre-calculated feature. I have plan to use some more feature to increase the accuracy.
I have made some googling to find which feature is used in Opencv's Knearest object for prediction, but I couldn't get that. 
could anyone please explain me Which feature vector does opencv's K-Nearest-Neighbor algorithm use to predict in pattern recognition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for what kind of features you need, there are lot .

1. Statistical features - ex , normalized density values , zone method, # "on" pixels
2. Structural features - ex , # intersections, # holes etc
3. Projection histogram features  etc

Like wise there are lot. Suggest you to read about few publications regarding OCR first, start from here [example](http://cns-classes.bu.edu/cn550/Readings/frey-slate-91.pdf)